# servicenow html link https misbehaving

Tags: html, http, https, href, servicenow

I am trying to create a html href link within service now to view a site within service now.
This is currently working only for "http" links but not for "https" links.

See working code to the right
`<a href="http://nu.nl" target="gsft_main">nu.nl</a>`

Any given site works except for the "https://" websites.
gsft_main is the iframe on the right where you can see by default your homepage.

Comment: i found the solution by goolge chrome to run unsafe scripts (kinda stupid but it are always the litle things you don't see

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution by goolge chrome to run unsafe scripts (kinda stupid but it are always the little things you don't see